# JQuery: Easier way to make this selection?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 9 'card' divs, each card has an hr tag with a '.card-border' class, which sets border-top to 5px and width to 60%. I want the width of the '.card-border' div to animate to 100% when '.card' is hovered, and it should revert to 60% width on mouseleave. Since there are 9 '.card' divs, I need to make sure that only the hovered '.card-border' expands. I know that I can do this by assigning IDs and selecting them each individually in my JavaScript, but I am hoping there is a simpler way to do this to avoid all of the repetitive code. Below is what I have so far, albeit using ID selectors, which I am trying to get away from.

```
<div id="family-card" class="card border-0">
  <hr id="family-border" class="card-border">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h5 class="card-title">Family Law</h5>
    <p class="card-text">***** is a full service Family Law Firm.</p>
    <a class="card-link move-right" href="./practice-areas/family-law.html">Learn more »</a>
  </div>
</div>


$('#family-card').mouseenter(function(){
    $('#family-border').animate({
        width: "100%"
    });
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $('#family-border').animate({
        width: "60%"
    });
});
}
```

I tried selecting the card class and then the firstChild, first(hr), etc. but it still affects the width of the whole card. below is an example of one of my failed attempts:

```
$('.card').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).first.animate({
        width: "100%"
    });
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).first.animate({
        width: "60%"
    });
});
}
```

Thank you in advanced for all your help!

Comment: `$(this).first.animate({` shouldn't have affected the width of any card. Can you expand on that explanation a bit?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com

Comment: `$(this).find('hr').animate({`

Comment: `.first()`, on `$(this)`, wouldn't do anything in this case. It would reduce the collection to the first element in the collection, and since this is an event handler, there's only 1 element in the collection anyway.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments.

@Kevin B - 
    $(this).first().animate({
For some reason, this does animate the parent element. I previously tried it, but just tried it again to be certain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need jQuery for something like this. Plain CSS is enough

```css
.card-border {
  width: 60%;
  transition: width .3s
}

.card:hover .card-border {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="family-card" class="card border-0">
  <hr id="family-border" class="card-border">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h5 class="card-title">Family Law</h5>
    <p class="card-text">***** is a full service Family Law Firm.</p>
    <a class="card-link move-right" href="./practice-areas/family-law.html">Learn more »</a>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="family-card" class="card border-0">
  <hr id="family-border" class="card-border">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h5 class="card-title">Family Law</h5>
    <p class="card-text">***** is a full service Family Law Firm.</p>
    <a class="card-link move-right" href="./practice-areas/family-law.html">Learn more »</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i would check it as right answer, i don't understand why some people want use js to do the CSS job

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This was actually very helpful as well.

Answer (score -1):

Using `.find(..)`, defined in JQuery 1.0, will search for the entered element and then apply any and all functions declared. So basically, using:
`$(this).find("#family-border")`, will select the first `#family-border` declared in `this`, and then apply the animation.

```js
$('#family-card').mouseenter(function(){
    $(this).find('#family-border').animate({
        width: "100%"
    });
}).mouseleave(function(){
    $(this).find('#family-border').animate({
        width: "60%"
    });
});
```

```css
#family-border {
width: 60%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="family-card" class="card border-0">
  <hr id="family-border" class="card-border">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h5 class="card-title">Family Law</h5>
    <p class="card-text">***** is a full service Family Law Firm.</p>
    <a class="card-link move-right" href="./practice-areas/family-law.html">Learn more »</a>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="family-card" class="card border-1">
  <hr id="family-border" class="card-border">
  <div class="card-block">
    <h5 class="card-title">Family Law</h5>
    <p class="card-text">***** is a full service Family Law Firm.</p>
    <a class="card-link move-right" href="./practice-areas/family-law.html">Learn more »</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Documentation: https://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: The code is low quality, and there's no explanation.

Comment: The quality issue i have with it is duplicate ID's are invalid, leaving that in place and coding around it will *work*, but it's wrong. The elements already have common classes that could potentially be used to select them using classnames instead.

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for, thank you Luicy. I think I will take Kevin B's comment on this and remove the IDs, though. This should work when selecting classes as well.